# How to prevent fast clicking at datagridview?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview at which I clicks at checkbox column to show element at second(visible/unvisible) control. When I'm fast clickick at checkboxcolumn, sometimes there is no reaction, at second control (MapDialog). To omit it I want to prevent user from fast clicking (blocking control for 0,5 s). But I don't know how to do it. I'm trying with SuspendLayout but it doesn't help.

```
private void dgvGeoObjects_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                bool visible = (bool)dgvGeoObjectsFirstView.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue;
                DataRow dataRow = ((DataRowView)dgvGeoObjectsFirstView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row;
                foreach (MapDisplayObjectBase sym in _symLayer.DisplayObjects)
                {
                    if (sym.UserObject == dataRow)
                        sym.Visible = visible;
                }

                mapControl.RefreshMap();
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it, by adding doubleclick event:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                bool visible = (bool)dgvGeoObjectsFirstView.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue;
                DataRow dataRow = ((DataRowView)dgvGeoObjectsFirstView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row;
                foreach (MapDisplayObjectBase sym in _symLayer.DisplayObjects)
                {
                    if (sym.UserObject == dataRow)
                        sym.Visible = !visible; //It's important !!
                }

                mapControl.RefreshMap();
            }
```

Thread.Sleep doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Add thread sleep. Use this only if you would like to process clicks which occurs during the sleep time. Because the thread will be in sleep mode but the clicks would be recorded during the sleep time and processed later.

You can use the following code to wait for 1 sec in your click event

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

The parameters to provide are in milliseconds.

So the resultant code can be:

```
private void dgvGeoObjects_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                bool visible = (bool)dgvGeoObjectsFirstView.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue;
                DataRow dataRow = ((DataRowView)dgvGeoObjectsFirstView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row;
                foreach (MapDisplayObjectBase sym in _symLayer.DisplayObjects)
                {
                    if (sym.UserObject == dataRow)
                        sym.Visible = visible;
                }

                mapControl.RefreshMap();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); //I think 0.1 second would be enough.
            }
            }
```

Method 2: If you want that the clicks must be ignored during the sleep time (say 0.01 secs), better use a timer. If some one clicks during the sleep time, just add

`e.Handled=true;`

in the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Before using Sleep and similar methods try to find out what causes the problem. The user quickly clicking is NOT the problem! the problem is something like "the UI isn't ready in time".

Try to solve that; you can't prevent the user from quickly clicking and swallowing click will lead to more clicks and frustration for the user.

If the controls/UI is to slow, try giving a visual clue such as an hourglass cursor, progress bar or disabled controls.

Comment: I think there isn't a problem in UI but his aim is to show the user that when you click 'something happens'. Because of immediate second click the user won't know that anything happened or not.